# Oracle to_date SQL formatting odd behavior

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, to-date

I've trawled the SO website thinking this is pretty obvious but alas I have not found one yet.
Basically the setup is as follows:

I have a string in a table like so:

> 06/22/2010 00:00:00

I do a select on it:

```
SELECT To_Date(item, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') from that_table
```

so that effectively I am doing

```
SELECT To_Date('06/22/2010 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') from that_table
```

My database returns:

> 22.06.2010 00:00:00

Now I know I can do a

```
to_char(to_Date('06/22/2010 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

but I need the select to return a date format (`MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS`), not a string. How can I do that?

**Edit:**
Real output:

> 22.06.2010 00:00:00

Desired output (in Date format):

> 06/22/2010 00:00:00

Comment: I re-read your question several times, but can't understand what do you want. At least, please add example of desired vs. real output
(edit) Aha, you mean default date formatting when no format is supplied!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a Date is a point in time, it has no format (like numbers: they don't have format). When you display the date, obviously it has to get a format: if you don't specifically give Oracle a format, the default format for your session will be used (session parameter NLS_DATE_FORMAT).

In consequence: use the DATE datatype for date arithmetics and storage (no format). Use the `to_char` function or something equivalent when you need to display the date (in a report or in the GUI).

Comment: But then how am I supposed to be able to do date comparisons (like date between today and tomorrow?)

Comment: @Rio: With comparison operators. _like date between today and tomorrow_ If all dates are stored as dates, then comparison would be something like `trunc(sysdate) <= date_in_question and date_in_question < trunc(sysdate) + 1`

Answer (score 5):

A DATE doesn't have a format, it is only formatted when converted to a character string for display purposes.  If you are using SQL Plus then when you display a DATE column (without using TO_CHAR to explicitly format it), SQL Plus itself performs a TO_CHAR conversion using the NLS_DATE_FORMAT setting:

```
SQL> select sysdate from dual;

SYSDATE
---------
23-JUN-10

SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';

Session altered.

SQL> select sysdate from dual;

SYSDATE
-------------------
2010-06-23 15:17:12
```

If you are not using SQL Plus, then whatever tool you are using will be doing something similar and may have a different way to specify the date format for display.